# Navbar Title not displaying

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

```
func navtitile(){

    let image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "image.jpg")!
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.image = image
    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView

}
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    navtitile()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

is there anything which should i change or name in storyboard??

Comment: Running your code in my system, I am getting the image.jpg on the navigationItem. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: but in my system its displaying title not the image.jpg. what should i look for

Comment: where is your image.jpg? Is it in the assets or the file system? Anyways, I don't think it would matter. If the image is not found, the code would crash. It would be better if you post a link to screenshot of your view controller in the storyboard, and also how it looks like on run time.

Comment: image is added in the asset folder

Answer (score 0):

The `viewController` should be embedded in a `UINavigationController` for this to work.

Follow these steps:

1. Go to Storyboard
2. Select the `UIViewController`
3. Click on "Editor" menu
4. Click on "Embed In"
5. Select "Navigation Controller"

---

Another thing, you have done:

```
UIImage(named: "image.jpg")!
```

Entire filename "image.jpg" should be given only if you have added the image in your project as a normal file.
*And don't force unwrap because if the object cannot be initialized, it will crash the app.*

Whereas... if the image has been added to the assets catalog, then you should be doing

```
UIImage(named: "image")
```

Comment: @FarasatNiazi Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

> You have to add Navigation controller if not added
>   Then it will work

Answer (score 0):

```
func navtitile(){

    let signinBTN   = UIButton(type: .system)
    signinBTN.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 30)
    signinBTN.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image"), for: .normal)
    let customBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: signinBTN)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customBarItem
}
```